# linux command: bad substitution

Tags: php, bash

I have a php script which takes the data from my DB and create an XML with exec command (on Linux OS).

*I know it's not the better way to create it, I'll update this later :)*

Anyway, my problem is that it provides an error 'bad substitution'.

Here is a simple PHP code which can show you the error...
You can notice that in order to create a "valid XML" (i.e.: well formatted), I manually escape some special chars:

```
<?php
$field="\${sao{}}\$";
$fieldParsed.=  str_replace(
    array("&",     "<",    ">",    '"',      "'",       "\\",   "`"),
    array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;", "&apos;",  "\\\\", "&#96;"), 
    $field
);
$data="<doc><field name=\"myname\">".$fieldParsed."</field></doc>";
$cmd='echo "'.addSlashes($data).'" >> /tmp/test.txt';
echo "\n\n".$cmd. "\n\n";
exec($cmd);
```

Would there be a way to avoid the "bash interpretation" of the $data?
i.e.: simply take it as it is...

NOTE: This code is only an example, so escape the $ won't be a valid answer. I'm searching for a general solution (if there is one)...

Thanks.

Comment: At what point exactly does the state of your variables not match your expectations? Where exactly do you get this error? If it really is in `exec()`, what is the precise content of `$cmd` at that time?

Comment: Well, maybe you could write `$data` to a file with php and read the file with a separate bash script that you call from php. At least that would avoid all the string concatenation and argument passing in php.

Comment: I think the problem is that when I run the exec, the bash interprets the $ as a "command"... e.g.: $field="my text with `backquote"; would also provide error if I did not replace "`" by "&#96"...

Comment: Off topic, but make sure that the unicode handling is fixed. `&#A485`  (`अ`) remains as `&#A485`   & not changed to `&amp;#A485`.

Comment: @anishane, so can you propose a solution instead of saying 'off topic' and downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that the solution was...
[escapeshellcmd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)

But not...because this will insert, e.g., { instead of {

**However, the problem seems to be the echo with double quotes (").**
*The same as in php, echo keep the string intact with single quote...(not like echo "my $var")*

If I use echo with single quote('), it's working fine.

So the code is something like:

```
<?php
$field="\${sao{}}\$";
$fieldParsed.=  
  str_replace(
    array("&",     "<",    ">",    '"',      "'"),
    array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;", "&apos;"), 
    $field
);
$data="<doc><field name=\"myname\">".$fieldParsed."</field></doc>";
$cmd="echo '".$data."' >> /tmp/test.txt";
echo "\n\n".$cmd. "\n\n";
exec($cmd);
```